# R - Ggplot dataframe do not sort data properly

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I am trying to plot data from a [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine+quality)

I used this function:

```r
wine_red <- read.csv2("winequality-red.csv")
ggplot(wine_red, aes(x=quality, y=alcohol)) + 
    scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
    geom_bin2d(binwidth=1)
```

But doing this I am obtaining a y axis which is not properly sorted: it goes from 10 -> 19 then 7 -> 9

[image: plot]

How can I sort it in the correct numeric order?

Comment: This happens if your y values are not numeric, it is perfectly sorted as characters are supposed to do. So make sure your y-values are numeric.

Comment: Okay and how to do this ? I tried a loop with `w_red[,a]<-as.numeric(w_red[,a])`, but the conversion got wrong values (0.4 became 5 and 0.56 became 57)

Comment: Get your example straight please. You provide `wine_red` as data in your ggplot, then use `data` in your aesthetics and now mention `w_red` as your data?

Comment: I added the line wich get the data (and corrected the second line)

Comment: You need to set your seperator and decimator in read.csv, the difference between read.csv and read.csv2 should be language/locale based where first uses the comma as seperator and the dot as decimator, while the other uses the semicolumn as seperator and the comma as decimator. Your data is a mix off... so anyhow with read.csv you have the right seperator, but the wrong decimator. so it sees your values as a string and not numeric. Long story short, I advise always to use only read.csv and set your preferences: `read.csv(file, sep = ";", dec = ".")` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine just as `data` you need to use `winequality_red` and for the `x=winequality_red$quality` and `y=winequality_red$alcohol`. Also below an example how to convert your data, to delimit the columns.

```
winequality_red <- read_delim("HERE SPECIFY YOUR DATA LOCATION", 
  ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

ggplot(winequality_red , aes(x=winequality_red$quality, y=winequality_red$alcohol)) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  geom_bin2d(binwidth=1)
```

[image]

Comment: The read_delim throws a parenthesis error

Comment: @Foxhunt exactly as you need something like "C:/Users/Downloads/winequality-red.csv". So, you need to specify the location of your data followed by the rest , + ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

Comment: Sorry, i missed a line, that was the `+ ";"` wich throws the error. I removed it and it worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- winequality_red
df %>% 
  select(quality, alcohol) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = quality, y=alcohol))+
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis")+
  geom_bin2d(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code, but got the same result as previous

Comment: Do we use the same dataframe: `winequality_red`

Comment: Yes it is, with quality wich goes from 3 to 8 and alcohol from 8.4 to 14.9. I only did a `read.csv2` before

Comment: use this instead `read.csv(file, sep = ";", dec = ".")`